# Implicit constructor in CUDA kernel call

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to pass some POD to a kernel which has as parameters some non-POD, and has non explicit constructors. Idea behind that is: allocate some memory on the host, pass the memory to the kernel, and it encapsulate the memory in the objects without the user to explicitly do that step.

The constructors are marked as __device__ code, but they are not called when passing the parameters, and I can't figure out why.

My question is not really related about how should I do the thing, but trying to understand what's happening behind the scenes.

Here an example (I'm using CUDA 5 with a GPU of capability 2.1, hence the printf).

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Test {
    __device__ Test() {
        printf("Default\n"),
        _n = 0;
    }
    __device__ Test(int n) {
        printf("Construct %d\n", n);
        _n = n;
    }
    __device__ Test(const Test &t) {
        printf("Copy constr %d\n", t._n);
        _n = t._n;
    }
    __device__ Test &operator=(const Test &t) {
        printf("Assignment %d\n", t._n);
        _n = t._n;
        return *this;
    }
    __device__ int calc() const {
        printf("Calculating %d\n", threadIdx.x + 10 * _n);
        return threadIdx.x + 10 * _n;
    }
    int _n;
};

__global__ void dosome(Test a, Test b) {
    printf("Kernel data %d %d\n", a._n, b._n);
    a.calc();
    b.calc();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    dosome<<<1, 2>>>(2, 3);
    cudaError_t cudaerr = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaerr != cudaSuccess)
        printf("kernel launch failed with error:\n\t%s\n",cudaGetErrorString(cudaerr));
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Forgot to say that, none of the constructor message is printed, but the calc and kernel message are.

EDIT2: Is it guaranteed that CUDA will initialize a Test object *before* copying it on the device?

Comment: Ok, I found it works (constructors are called) if I remove the __device__ qualifiers from the constructor, probably because the object is constructed on the host, pushed on the stack and then copied to device, but... In that case the object is not constructable on the device!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to see a constructor just like a normal method. If you qualify it with `__host__`, then you'll be able to call it host-side. If you qualify it with `__device__`, you'll be able to call it device-side. If you qualify it with both, you'll be able to call it on both sides.

What happens when you do `dosome<<<1, 2>>>(2, 3);` is that the two objects are implictly constructed (because your constructor is not `explicit`, so maybe that's confusing you too) host side and then `memcpy`'d to the device. There is no copy-constructor involved in the process.

Let's illustrate this:

```
    __global__ void dosome(Test a, Test b) {
        a.calc();
        b.calc();
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        dosome<<<1, 2>>>(2, 3); // Constructors must be at least __host__
        return 0;
    }

// Outputs:
Construct 2 (from the host side)
Construct 3 (from the host side)
```

Now if you change your kernel to take `int`s instead of `Test`:

```
__global__ void dosome(int arga, int argb) {
    // Constructors must be at least __device__
    Test a(arga);
    Test b(argb);
    a.calc();
    b.calc();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    dosome<<<1, 2>>>(2, 3);
    return 0;
}

// Outputs:
Construct 2 (from the device side)
Construct 3 (from the device side)
```

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly like I imagined. Do you know if is it guaranteed that constructors are called on host side?

Comment: What do you mean? Constructors on the host here are called because of an implicit conversion from `int` to `Test`. That's C++ related, not CUDA related!

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was hoping. Can you please add a reference for your answer? (I mean, the answer above, not the one in comments)

Comment: I'm afraid I have no specific reference for that, other than the CUDA Programming Guide.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found it works (constructors are called) if I add both __host__ and __device__ qualifiers to the constructors. The constructor of the objects happened at host side, and then they were copied to device (stack?). This is why the constructors weren't called: they were device code (but what was called on the host side?!?)

Using both __host__ and __device__ in the constructors allowed to use the class without problems.

EDIT: Still, I'm not sure if the construction always happens before the copy to device.